# Failed running activator run after play-slick upgrade

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have upgraded build.sbt to use the latest play-slick (2.0.0) and after all was downloaded and the application set to run I got this exception.

`
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.api.Logger$.init(Ljava/io/File;Lscala/Enumeration$Value;)V
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:88)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:61)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDev(DevServerStart.scala:60)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala:50)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:207)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:73)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.play$sbt$run$PlayRun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:73)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:99)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:52)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 31/ago/2016 23:23:25

`

This is my build.sbt
`

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.22"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  //jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0"
)

//libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.21"
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.21"

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

libraryDependencies += "com.sksamuel.scrimage" %% "scrimage-core" % "2.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.sksamuel.scrimage" %% "scrimage-io-extra" % "2.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.sksamuel.scrimage" %% "scrimage-filters" % "2.1.0"

`
and my plugins.sbt

`
cat project/plugins.sbt 
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

//offline := true

`
I already tried disabling dependencies but that did not solve the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the version matrix in the readme. https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your play version "2.4" seems to be incompatible with the upgraded Slick version.

```
//try this instead in your plugins.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.x")
```